# how to get sum of input fields using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dynamic, sum

this is my script to add input fields dynamically, in this part, the max of fields is 10.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      x++;
      var form_colis = '<div><input type="text" placeholder="Poids" name="poids[]"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Longueur" name="longueurs[]"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Largeur" name="largeurs[]"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Hauteur" name="hauteurs[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>';
      //$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
      $(wrapper).append(form_colis); //add input box
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; 
              <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
            </button>


  <div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Poids" name="poids[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Longueur" name="longueurs[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Largeur" name="largeurs[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hauteur" name="hauteurs[]">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to add fields in function of the sum of previous fields name. eg. for fields name poids[], if the sum is higher than 100, the user can't add fieldset, else, he can.

I hope that you understand what I mean.

thank you in advance

Comment: if the sum of ALL fields is more than 100, then it is necessary to forbid adding fields?

Comment: Yes, if sum poids[] >100 ==> user is not allowed to add fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that will calculate. I made the code shorter too - please note the CSS changes and the added class to item div

I assume you only want to test that poids > 100 ?

```js
$(function() {
  var max_fields = 10;
  var $wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const vals = $("> .item input[name^=poids]",$wrapper).map(function() { return +this.value }).get()
    const val = vals.length === 0 ? 0 : vals.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
    if ($("> .item",$wrapper).length < max_fields && val < 100) {
      const $form_colis = $(".item").first().clone();
      $form_colis.find("input").val("");
      $wrapper.append($form_colis); //add input box
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }
  });

  $wrapper.on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
  })
});
```

```css
.container1 .item:first-of-type .delete {
  display: none;
}

.delete { text-decoration: none; color: red; }

.add_form_field { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add_form_field">Add New Field ✚</button>
<div class="container1">
  <div class="item">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Poids" name="poids[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Longueur" name="longueurs[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Largeur" name="largeurs[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hauteur" name="hauteurs[]">
    <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, then check this solution, modified by me. If the sum of all fields is exactly less than 100, then new fields are added, otherwise they are not added. Was it necessary?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  
  
  var max_fields = 10;
  var wrapper = $(".container1");
  var add_button = $(".add_form_field");

  var x = 1;
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
  $('.inputs:last-of-type').each(function(){
    var sum_inputs = 0;
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
      sum_inputs += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
          
    if (x < max_fields && sum_inputs < '100') {
      x++;
      var form_colis = '<div class="inputs"><input type="text" placeholder="Poids" name="poids[]"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Longueur" name="longueurs[]"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Largeur" name="largeurs[]"/> <input type="text" placeholder="Hauteur" name="hauteurs[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>';
      //$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>'); //add input box
      $(wrapper).append(form_colis); //add input box
    } else {
      alert('You Reached the limits')
    }

    });
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  }) 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container1">
  <button class="add_form_field">Add New Field &nbsp; 
              <span style="font-size:16px; font-weight:bold;">+ </span>
            </button>


  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Poids" name="poids[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Longueur" name="longueurs[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Largeur" name="largeurs[]">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hauteur" name="hauteurs[]">
  </div>
</div>
```